# Почему если переменная равна то выдает то что она не равна?Программа выдает не то

Tags: python

Дело в том,что я начинающий программист и пытаюсь сделать некоторые функции на питоне.У меня если я допустим пишу: "Включи ютуб" То у меня включает ютуб а потом выдает поиск в интернете по запросу: Включи ютуб.Вот мой код:

```
import random
import time
print("Привет!Я - ВасяПро228!Я голосовой помощник!Вот мои команды")
print("Включи ютуб")
print("Дай рандомное число")
print("Кто создал тебя?")
def main():
    b = input("Что вы хотите? ")
    if b == "Включи ютуб":
        print("Включаю")
        webbrowser.open('www.youtube.com/', new=2)
    if b == "включи ютуб":
        print("Включаю")
        webbrowser.open('www.youtube.com/', new=2)
    if b == "дай рандомное число":
        c = input("От какого числа вы хотите? ")
        d = input("До какого числа вы хотите? ")
        e = random.randint(float(c),float(d))
        print("Рандомное число: " + str(e))
    if b == "Дай рандомное число":
        c = input("От какого числа вы хотите? ")
        d = input("До какого числа вы хотите? ")
        e = random.randint(float(c),float(d))
        print("Рандомное число: " + str(e))
    if b == "Кто создал тебя?":
        
        webbrowser.open('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCyxmi2K_-EtZWXP_go1YJ1A', new=2)
    if b == "кто создал тебя?":
        
        webbrowser.open('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCyxmi2K_-EtZWXP_go1YJ1A', new=2)
    if b == "Привет":
        print("Привет,я - ВасяПро228!")
    elif b == "привет":
        print("Привет,я - ВасяПро228!")
    elif b == "Как дела?":
        print("Хорошо")
    elif b == "как дела?":
        print("Хорошо")
    elif b == "как дела":
        
        print("Хорошо")
    elif b == "Как дела":
        
        print("Хорошо")
    else:
        print("Поиск в интернете по запросу: " + b)
        time.sleep(1)
        def urlify(s):
            
            s = s.strip().split(" ")
            return ("%20").join(s)
    webbrowser.open('https://yandex.ru/search/?text=' + b + '&lr=11212&clid=9582', new=2)
    
    time.sleep(2)    
    
        
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        main()
```

И выдает мне вот это:

> Что вы хотите? Включи ютуб
> Включаю
> Поиск в интернете по запросу: Включи ютуб

И кроме ютуба включает поиск.Как исправить?Пробовал менять ифы

Comment: все кроме первого `if` замените на `elif`

Comment: Чтобы не копировать код для случаев с заглавными буквами и без, используй `b = b.lower()` чтобы заменить в строке все заглавные буквы на строчные.

Answer (score 1):

Извини, что не по главной теме. Но хочу дать пару "улучшений кода"

Вместо кучи условий лучше привести вводимый текст к одному "формату". Введу переменную user_input (намного круче, когда у переменных понятные имена):

```
user_input = input()
user_input = user_input.lower()
user_input = user_input.replace(' ', '')
if user_input == 'включиютюб':
    '# И сюда уже условие'
```

---

Команды с рандомом можно сократить. Как минимум можно сразу при вводе указать тип переменной:

```
rand_1 = float(input('От какого числа вы хотите?'))
rand_2 = float(input('До какого числа вы хотите?'))
```

Затем нам из библиотеки "random" нужна только одна функция. Чтобы не нагружать систему импортируем только её. В самом начале вместо `import random` запишем `from random imort randint`

На выходе:

```
rand_1 = float(input('От какого числа вы хотите?'))
rand_2 = float(input('До какого числа вы хотите?'))
rand_number = randint(rand_1, rand_1)
print('Рандомное число:', rand_number)
```

Можно и в одну строку, но выглядеть будет не красиво

Answer (score 0):

Нужно сделать как минимум две вещи, во первых, как написали в комментарии:

> все кроме первого if замените на elif

во вторых, перенесите строку `webbrowser.open('https://yandex.ru/search/?text=' + b + '&lr=11212&clid=9582', new=2)`
в блок else, для этого добавьте просто еще один отступ

```
import random
import time
print("Привет!Я - ВасяПро228!Я голосовой помощник!Вот мои команды")
print("Включи ютуб")
print("Дай рандомное число")
print("Кто создал тебя?")
def main():
    b = input("Что вы хотите? ")
    if b == "Включи ютуб":
        print("Включаю")
        webbrowser.open('www.youtube.com/', new=2)
    elif b == "включи ютуб":
        print("Включаю")
        webbrowser.open('www.youtube.com/', new=2)
    elif b == "дай рандомное число":
        c = input("От какого числа вы хотите? ")
        d = input("До какого числа вы хотите? ")
        e = random.randint(float(c),float(d))
        print("Рандомное число: " + str(e))
    elif b == "Дай рандомное число":
        c = input("От какого числа вы хотите? ")
        d = input("До какого числа вы хотите? ")
        e = random.randint(float(c),float(d))
        print("Рандомное число: " + str(e))
    elif b == "Кто создал тебя?":
        
        webbrowser.open('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCyxmi2K_-EtZWXP_go1YJ1A', new=2)
    elif b == "кто создал тебя?":
        
        webbrowser.open('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCyxmi2K_-EtZWXP_go1YJ1A', new=2)
    elif b == "Привет":
        print("Привет,я - ВасяПро228!")
    elif b == "привет":
        print("Привет,я - ВасяПро228!")
    elif b == "Как дела?":
        print("Хорошо")
    elif b == "как дела?":
        print("Хорошо")
    elif b == "как дела":
        
        print("Хорошо")
    elif b == "Как дела":
        
        print("Хорошо")
    else:
        print("Поиск в интернете по запросу: " + b)
        time.sleep(1)
        def urlify(s):
            
            s = s.strip().split(" ")
            return ("%20").join(s)
        webbrowser.open('https://yandex.ru/search/?text=' + b + '&lr=11212&clid=9582', new=2)
    
    time.sleep(2)    
    
        
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        main()
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо тебе!

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)